# undefined method `get_access_token' while implementing koala gem in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I want to implement koala gem in rails app
But i am getting an error "undefined method get_access_token' 
My facebook controller code is

```
  class FacebookController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
  unless current_user.facebook_oauth_setting
      @oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new("app-id", "secret", "http://#{request.host}:#{request.port}/callback")
      session["oauth_obj"] = @oauth
      redirect_to @oauth.url_for_oauth_code
    else
      redirect_to "/facebook_profile"
    end
  end

  def callback
    unless current_user.facebook_oauth_setting

      @oauth = session["oauth_obj"]
      Rails.logger.info("**************#{@oauth}***************")
      Rails.logger.info("**********#{params[:code]}*************")

   FacebookOauthSetting.create({:access_token => @oauth.get_access_token(params[:code]), :user_id => current_user.id})  

      redirect_to "/facebook_profile"
    else
      redirect_to "/"
    end
  end

  def facebook_profile
    if current_user.facebook_oauth_setting
      @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user.facebook_oauth_setting.access_token)
      @profile = @graph.get_object("me")
      @picture = @graph.get_picture("me")
      @feed = @graph.get_connections("me","feed")
      @friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
    else
      redirect_to "/"
    end
  end

end
```

My model to store access token is

```
class TwitterOauthSetting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

end
```

My migration to store access_token is

```
class CreateFacebookOauthSettings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :facebook_oauth_settings do |t|
      t.string :access_token
      t.integer :user_id
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `undefined method get_access_token` for what? Please post the full error message

Comment: undefined method `get_access_token' for #<Hash:0x007efff63efe98>.I am getting this error in this line "FacebookOauthSetting.create({:access_token => @oauth.get_access_token(params[:code]), :user_id => current_user.id}) "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the `@oauth` object inside the `callback` method rather than bringing it from the `session`. So do this:

```
@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new("app-id", "secret", "http://#{request.host}:#{request.port}/callback")    
FacebookOauthSetting.create(:access_token => @oauth.get_access_token(params[:code]), :user_id => current_user.id)
```

It should solve your problem.

Comment: what do you see if you print this: `puts #{@oauth.class.inspect}` AND ``puts #{@oauth.inspect}``

Comment: The type of `@oauth` object should be `Koala::Facebook::OAuth`. Make sure this is the case.

Comment: By doing this puts #{@oauth.class.inspect} i m getting===========Hash=============By doing this puts #{@oauth.inspect}
==========={"app_id"=>"app-id", "app_secret"=>"app_secret", "oauth_callback_url"=>"http://localhost:3000/callback"}==============

Comment: That's the problem. It has to be `Koala::Facebook::OAuth` type as per the documentation. The you can call: `@oauth.get_access_token...`

Comment: i used the same  type of @oauth  object u can see this in index method

Comment: try to use `@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new("app-id", "secret", "http://#{request.host}:#{request.port}/callback")` in the same place as `   FacebookOauthSetting.create(:access_token => @oauth.get_access_token(params[:code]), :user_id => current_user.id)
` without storing `@oauth` in the session. See if that works first. I did not work with this before. But seems like the `@oauth` object gets modified when you get this back from the session.

Comment: Nice, what did you do?

Comment: i used  same thing as u suggested me in above comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89120/discussion-between-rajesh-choudhary-and-k-m-rakibul-islam).

Answer (score -1):

type of object should be `Koala::Facebook`